# Duda buscar elementos en concreto en jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Hola tengo un problema y es que yo he creado una tabla con javascript entonces lo que yo he hecho es que cada vez que introduzco un nombre, apellido y teléfono válido lo añado a la tabla, entonces no sé como poner que solamente me elija el nombre. Lo que pasa que cuando pongo por ejemplo "ro" para que me busque el nombre de "roberto" me borra todas las filas y no sé porque motivo. Por lo demás no estoy seguro si puede haber algún fallo más. Lo que se supone que hace el filtrado es mirar que letras has puesto en el input que está fuera del formulario y compararlo con cada una de las filas que se crean en la tabla y después elimina las filas que no cumplen la condición del filtro.

Aquí el código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="author" content="axel">
        <title>Examen. Ejercicio 2</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilo.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../agenda_javascript_y_jquery/ejercicio_2.js"></script>
        <script src="../agenda_javascript_y_jquery/filtrar_contactos.js"></script>
        
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>filtrado contactos</h1>
        <form action="ejemplo.php" method="post" value = "">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>agenda</legend>
                <label for="nombre">Nombre:</label>
                <input type="text" id="nombre">
                <label for="apellido">Apellido:</label>
                <input type="text" id="apellido">
                <label for="telephone">Teléfono:</label>
                <input type="tel" id="telephone">
    
    
    
                <input type="button" onclick="add()" value="Añadir">
                <input type="button" onclick="listarElArray()" value="Listar array">
                <input type="button" onclick="borrarElArray()" value="Borrar array">
                
            
                
            </fieldset>
        </form>
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="text" id = "filtrado">
        <button type="button" id ="button1">Filtrar</button>
    
    
        <table id="registros">
          
            <tr>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Apellido</th>
                <th>Teléfono</th>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

aquí el filtrado

```
    $( () => {
        // Bindea el CTA directo al botón
        $(document).on('click', '#button1', function(){
          // Sacamos el valor y lo pasamos a minusculas para manejarlo
          const value = $('#filtrado').val().toLowerCase();
          // Obtenemos todas las celdas con los nombres
          $('td').each( function() {
            const name = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
            // Guardamos el <tr> padre de la celda del nombre
            const row  = $(this).parent('tr');
            // Si existe coincidencia, lo muestra, caso contrario lo oculta
            name.includes( value ) ? row.show() : row.hide();
          });
          
        });
      
      
      } )
```

aquí creo la tabla con javascript donde voy añadiendo cada una de las filas cada vez que escribo los valores en el formulario

```
// Aquí creo los arrays vacios donde meto los registros del formulario en cada correspondiente array.
var nombres = []
var telefonos = []
var apellidos = []

function add() {
    debugger
    var mensaje = ""
    var nombre = document.getElementById("nombre").value
    var apellido = document.getElementById("apellido").value
    var telefono = document.getElementById("telephone").value;

// Validación del nombre, apellido y teléfono
    if (/\D{3}/.test(nombre) == false) {
        mensaje += "\n-Nombre (3 caracteres de TEXTO o mas)\n";
    }

    if (/\D{4}/.test(apellido) == false) {
        mensaje += "\n-Apellido (4 caracteres o mas)\n";
    }

    if(/^\d{9}$/.test(telefono) == false) {
        mensaje += "\n[INCORRECTO] Introduce un número de teléfono correcto\n";
    }

// Aquí introduzco cada elemento en su array correspondiente
    if (mensaje == "") {
        nombres.push(nombre)
        telefonos.push(telefono)
        apellidos.push(apellido)
        alert("Los elementos han sido añadidos a la tabla")
    }
// Si los campos no son correctos, salta un error con los campos que hay que cambiar
    else {
        mensaje = "Los siguientes campos se encuentran vacios o no son validos" + mensaje
        alert(mensaje)
        return false
    }
}
function listarElArray() {
    var tabla = document.getElementById("registros")
    if (nombres.length == 0) {
        alert("La lista esta vacia")
    }
    else {
        // Aquí se crean cada una de las filas en la tabla para insertar los registros
        for (contador = tabla.rows.length; contador > 1; contador--) {
            tabla.deleteRow(contador - 1)
        }
        for (indice = 0; indice < nombres.length; indice++) {
            var fila = tabla.insertRow(indice + 1)
            var celda = fila.insertCell(0)
            celda.innerHTML = nombres[indice]
            var celda = fila.insertCell(1)
            celda.innerHTML = apellidos[indice]
            var celda = fila.insertCell(2)
            celda.innerHTML = telefonos[indice]
        }
    }
}
function borrarElArray() {
    var tabla = document.getElementById("registros")
    if (nombres.length == 0) {
        alert("La lista esta vacia")
    }
    // Aquí se borra el registro que has creado en el formulario
    else {
        for (contador = tabla.rows.length; contador > 1; contador--) {
            tabla.deleteRow(contador - 1)
        }
        nombres = []
        telefonos = []
        apellidos = []
    }
}
```